# Function returns 'undefined' while it could get the correct result inside the function body

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a html that contains below content:

```
<div class="ui-btn-text">
<a id="12323" class="listviewLines ui-link-inherit" href="" /></div>
<div class="ui-btn-text">
<a id="23534" class="listviewLines ui-link-inherit" href="" /></div>
<div class="ui-btn-text">
<a id="12312" class="listviewLines ui-link-inherit" href="" /></div>
```

I want to extract the id value based on the index of the  tag, so I write below function:

```
function getId(index) {
    $('.ui-btn-text > a').each(function(i) {
        if (index == i) {
            alert($(this).attr("id"));
            return ($(this).attr("id"));
        }
    });
}
```

and then when I call getId(0), the result is "undefined". I am new to javascript, could anyone help me?

Also, is there a function in jQuery that could directly return content with a index parameter, without iterate all children?

Comment: Is this your real HTML code? Because you are missing the cloding tags for the divs. (`</DIV>`)

Comment: No, I have simplified the real HTML to clarify my problem.

Comment: Thank all you guys, I learned a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
function getId(index) {
    return $($('.ui-btn-text > a')[index]).attr("id");
}
```

this is zero based, of course.

Answer (score 2):

The inner anonymous function passed as an argument to `each` returns. `getId` doesn't return anything, that is `undefined`.

You can get the N'th child of an element by using the [N-th child selector](http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/)

In your case the selector would be `$('.ui-btn-text > a:nth-child('+index+')')`

Answer (score 2):

```
function getId(index) {
    var ret;
    $('.ui-btn-text > a').each(function(i) {
        if (index == i) {
            ret = $(this).attr("id");
            return false; // stop internal loop by jQuery
        }
    });
    return ret;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There's no `return` statement in the `getId` function. (not counting the `return` which is inside an anonymous function).

Answer (score 1):

you're looking for [nth-child selector](http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/):

```
$('.ui-btn-text a:nth-child(' + index+')')
```